# To use If statement all Dataframe value in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
  col0  col1  col2
0     0     1     1
1     1     1     1
2     1     0     1
3     0     0     1
```

I want to use conditional statements to all values.

Statement is 1 = a , 0 = b

So I want to get results like this:

```
   col0 col1 col2
0   b    a    a
1   a    a    a
2   a    b    a
3   b    b    a
```

I know pandas offer Boolean function. (ex) dfs = df > 0

But I don't know how can I solve that. 
I tried apply function to solve that problem. 
But I failed.
I would be grateful if you could give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about Option 3, but I think Option 1 is the most pythonic way to do it.

## Option 1

Use `replace` and dictionary:

```
df.replace({0:'b',1:'a'})
```

Output:

```
  col0 col1 col2
0    b    a    a
1    a    a    a
2    a    b    a
3    b    b    a
```

## Option 2

Build a new dataframe with `np.where`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df,'a','b'), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
  col0 col1 col2
0    b    a    a
1    a    a    a
2    a    b    a
3    b    b    a
```

## Option 3

Use `applymap` and lambda function:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 'a' if x == 1 else 'b')
```

Output:

```
  col0 col1 col2
0    b    a    a
1    a    a    a
2    a    b    a
3    b    b    a
```

Comment: Simple and useful. Thank you very much. Can I ask one more question? If I solve that problem to use if statement. Can I solve that method?

Comment: Yes, you can use a method in the applymap also.